# Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have created a SpringBoot/SpringSecurity/React web app that runs fine locally but when I try to run it on the DigitalOcean production server, it fails with

> Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this
>   resource

I am NOT using oauth2, just spring security. The home page does not require authentication so I don't understand the error.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to add this to you WebApplicationInitializer class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Where would I find the WebApplicationInitializer class?  I did a search on the codebase for it but the only place it was found was in the jar file created by the build.  Did not show up in the source code.

Comment: or add to your main class

Comment: Ok, I added it to the main class.  Unfortunately didn't help. Still getting same error.